# Can Gnome Terminal set WM_URGENT?

Tags: window-manager, gnome-terminal, xmonad

I'd like for gnome terminal to set the `WM_URGENT` window manager hint on bell. Is this possible?

[This bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/272749) suggests it's not but does anyone know another way.

Basically I'm running XMonad under Gnome and have XMobar set to display hidden workspaces with windows that have that hint set (i.e. for new emails). That part of the functionality works because I can use this while running mutt under urxvt (which does set this hint) but I'd like to use gnome's terminal as my default terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a patch.

http://mikelward.com/news/2008/11/terminal-that-tells-you-when-its-done.html

The patch is [here](http://bugzilla-attachments.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=122001&action=view) but it's against revision 3145 from the SVN.

You might want to consider alternatives such as the Terminator or urxvt.
I had gnome-terminal as my default terminal too, but I'm trying to configure terminator to accomplish the same task.

It doesn't have a friendly GUI to make changes in profiles, but it has a friendly text file for the configuration.